# Как в Django проекте найти или достать все URLы которые есть впроекте?

Tags: django, url, django-urls

Для тестирования (я не разработчик) мне нужно достать из Джанго проекта все возможные ссылки, которые есть на моем проекте (не знаю как) и дальше они будут проверены (это я знаю как). Подскажите, как это сделать?

Comment: В общем случае это невозможно, так как ссылок может быть сгенерировано бесконечно много. В частном случае можно подключить [django-extensions](https://pypi.org/project/django-extensions/) и посмотреть все urlpatterns командой `manage.py show_urls`

Comment: Да, уже выводил, но это в консоли. В общем нашел решение, но там много лишнего выгребается, но это уже отфильтровать - полегче будет.